# Selenium Grid: Capabilities and Platform.WINDOWS7?

Tags: selenium

I'm using Selenium 2.9.0. When configuring a `WebDriver` grid node is there a way to specify that the node is capable of running a browser on Windows 7 rather than say Vista? So for example:

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "internet explorer",
          "maxInstances": 2,
      "platform": "WINDOWS7"
        }
      ],
    "configuration":
       // rest 
}
```

When I try this configuration the Hub reports

> HTTP ERROR: 500
>   No enum const class org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS7

Is there a way to distinguish between the two operating systems on the Grid?

Answer (score 0):

There is no enum WINDOWS7 in class org.openqa.selenium.Platform (as of Selenium 2.15). 
I am running test on XP, VISTA and WINDOWS7, so I designated enum value WINDOWS to WINDOWS7.

If you run Selenium Grid node with for example following attributes:

```
-role node  -browser browserName=firefox,version=8,platform=WINDOWS
```

you can distinguish between XP, VISTA and WINDOWS7

Comment: but you won't know what you get right? and if you try to get your caps from the RWD they are wrong either... that's a serious problem I think

Answer (score 0):

Machine 1-"HUB"

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role hub
```

machine 2-"NODE"

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -host **nodeip** -role node -hub http://**hubip**:4444/grid/register -port 5555
```

replace `hubip` as your hub machine ip address and `nodeip` as remote machine.

[More information on selenium grid.](http://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html)